# Как взаимодействовать с cmd в тихом режиме?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, subprocess, x509certificate

Есть задача: проверить сертификат X509 в кодировке ASN1 на отзыв.
Вместо того, чтобы писать много кода, используя OpenSSL, хочется делать это через командную строку, потому что проверка состоит из одной строки.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("test.txt", 'w') as file:
        reply = subprocess.run(['certutil', '-verify', pathfile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='cp1251')
        file.write(reply.stdout)
```

И этот скрипт прекрасно работает, если его оставлять в виде питон-скрипта, но при работе вызывает командную строку. После того, как я его конвертирую в бесконсольный exe-файл, все ломается.Ловлю исключение:

```
(<class 'OSError'>, OSError(9, 'Неверный дескриптор', None, 6, None), <traceback object at 0x000001B3CAE73888>)
```

Если я конвертирую его в консольный exe-файл, все прекрасно работает.
Можно ли как-то сделать через subprocess, чтобы проверка была через командную строку и при этом exe-шник работал?

Comment: Раз уж вы прибиты к винде гвоздями с цертутилом, тогда что вам мешает вызвать AllocConsole в коде перед вызовом вашей утилиты? или можно перенаправить вывод в файл через > и < и потом его прочитать.

Comment: или попробовать переназначить стдин и стдаут. когда у вас консоль не аллоцирована, они не открыты, вот приложение и не работает. p1 = Popen(["openssl", "verify", "-CApath", capath, "-crl_check_all"], 
           stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
message, error = p1.communicate(certificate)
verified = ("OK" in message and not "error" in message)